# Update Button Label

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I have a JavaScript function for a HTML button click event in aspx page and a server method in the page code-behind.  When the HTML button is clicked by the user it will be processed, and the button will display an answer.

How do I get the button label to be updated, as it is using AJAX?

When I try to set the update somewhere, the page does not update the button.  The text box updates work fine.  As one can see from the code below, `btnDivide` has a set value of "Get Weather" at the moment, but I need to change it once the user is done processing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[

// This function creates an asynchronous call to the service
function makeCall(operation){
    var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;


    // If user filled out these fields, call the service
    if(n1 && n2){

        // Instantiate a service proxy
        var proxy = new Service();

        // Call correct operation on vf cproxy       
        switch(operation){

            case "gridOne":
proxy.Calculate(AjaxService.Operation.getWeather,n1,n2,    
onSuccess, onFail, null);
                btnDivide.value = "TestNewValue";

                break;
            case "gridTwo":
*******
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #result
    {
        width: 1010px;
    }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Ajax TicTacToe</h1>
<p>Major City: <input type="text" id="num1" onclick="return 
num1_onclick()" /></p>
<p>Country: <input type="text" id="num2" onclick="return num2_onclick()"
 /></p> 
&nbsp;
<br />
<input id="btnDivide" type="button" onclick="return makeCall('gridOne');" 
    value="Get Weather" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function onSuccess(mathResult){
    document.getElementById("result").value = mathResult;
    document.getElementById("btnDivide").value = "test";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an event handler to endRequest event
take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx